# Ionic Top Navigation Bar?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

**Ionic Top Navigation Bar**

Hello! 
I need help making a Top Naviagtion Bar in my Ionic Project. There is no Doumentation about a Top Navigation Bar and I just can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: what type of navigation bar do you want ??

Comment: Ionic gives you two types of navigation. A sidebar and tabs. But i want one on the top. Like this (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp). But with Ionic.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="top">
   <ion-tab-button (click)="openExample()">
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Example</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button (click)="openCartExample()">
      <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Example Cart</ion-label>
   </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tab-bar>
```

[image]

Comment: good call. But it should not look like a mobile version more like a real website.(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)